# Changing part of HTML page in CDHtmlDialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing an interface in MFC which requires a (very) deep visual customization. I thought that it might be easier doing it using CDHtmlDialog base class because restylings (which can occur frequently) will be easier.

Now, my dialog has a left menu divided in sections and choices and a central window which changes accordingly to the voice selected. The left part is easy to design but: how to update the central part, what's the most efficient way?

- Storing in cpp the HTML and switching it like in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1094/the-mfc-cdhtmldialog-class) example.
- Storing different HTML pages and reloading them like in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f48e230-2bd6-4f6b-b68a-e7d4515510cb/cdhtmldialog-changing-html-file-dynamically?forum=vcgeneral) example.
- Your best practice here...

Comment: The first example you have show is more about creating html files, evidently that's not what you are doing. Just use the html files and store it in resource, or keep them as separate files on disk. If the page has pictures and links then make a html sub directory and put all the html files in there.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani So, you're suggesting second option: duplicating the menu for every page.

Comment: Actually I don't think I understand the requirements of your app, and I now am not sure what examples you are referring to. I thought the question was about storing html files.